# Unity Scene working correctly in Simulator but not loading correctly on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have created a Unity Match 3 game, which I want to export to Android. It works on the web, it works when you run it on Windows, but as soon as I export it on Android it doesn't work anymore. I have all the scenes loaded, so that can't be the problem. Here you can see it working in the simulator (left) but not on mobile (right, screen mirror): [Video](https://youtu.be/aW9ADSaaoXo)
[image: Build Settings]
[image: Settings for Android]
[image: Android Tools]
[image: Web Version]
I am loading the Scene via the SceneManager Load Scene Method:

```
 public void OnButtonPress(string levelName)
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading Scene: " + levelName);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(levelName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
```

Can anyone give me any information on what i could be doing wrong?

Unity Version: 2022.2.21f1(also tried Version 2021.3.24f1)
Phone: OnePlusNord2 5G(DN2103) Android Version 12

[image: Debugging Output]
Here is the Debug Output, maybe someone can find an error here, i already debugged it via Android Debugging, but either do not understand the error or i can simply find no error:

> 2023-05-30 15:33:03.286 29685-30436 Unity                   com.daltonlima.com.Match3            I  Loading Scene: Level04
> UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
> UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
> Match3.LevelSelect:OnButtonPress(String) (at C:\Schule\bachelor_flutter_crush\projekt_flutter_crush\unity\Match3\Assets\Scripts\LevelSelect.cs:36)
> UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall`1:Invoke(String) (at \home\bokken\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Export\UnityEvent\UnityEvent.cs:219) UnityEngine.Events.CachedInvokableCall`1:Invoke(Object[]) (at \home\bokken\build\output\unity\unity\Runtime\Export\UnityEvent\UnityEvent.cs:357)
> UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke() (at \home\bokken\build\output\unity\unity\artifacts\generated\UnityEvent\UnityEvent_0.cs:69)
> UnityEngine.UI.Button:Press() (at .\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\UI\Core\Button.cs:70)
> UnityEngine.UI.Button:OnPointerClick(PointerEventData) (at .\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\UI\Core\Button.cs:114)
> UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(IPointe
> 2023-05-30 15:33:03.301 29685-30529 Unity                   com.daltonlima.com.Match3            D  Unloading 5 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
> 2023-05-30 15:33:03.361 29685-30436 Unity                   com.daltonlima.com.Match3            D  UnloadTime: 5.955692 ms
> 2023-05-30 15:33:03.387 29685-30436 Unity                   com.daltonlima.com.Match3            D  Unloading 20 unused Assets / (25.1 KB). Loaded Objects now: 1291.
> Memory consumption went from 73.2 MB to 73.1 MB.
> 2023-05-30 15:33:03.387 29685-30436 Unity                   com.daltonlima.com.Match3            D  Total: 4.805923 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.179923 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.054385 ms MarkObjects: 4.314769 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.255308 ms)
> 2023-05-30 15:33:03.390 29685-30436 Unity                   com.daltonlima.com.Match3            I  Started LevelColors
> UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
> UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
> Match3.LevelColors:Start() (at C:\Schule\bachelor_flutter_crush\projekt_flutter_crush\unity\Match3\Assets\Scripts\LevelColors.cs:26)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow i managed to make it work, by simply changing the `m_ShowUnitySplashScreen = 0`
to `m_ShowUnitySplashScreen = 1`

I do not fully understand why it is working now, but it somehow does. Thanks anyway for your input. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

With only those information is not possible to say what the problem really is.
For example the problem can be where you save/load data to/from the hard disk or a not compatible with mobile shader or something else...
You should try to debug your game follow the instruction here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-debugging-on-an-android-device.html

that way you can actually see the error when the game start on your device and try to correct it.

EDIT.
I do it like this:

```
Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("PreviousScene")); 
SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Name New Level", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

Not sure if it will work for you too. Also since I stop time when the game is in the menu before that I will set

```
Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
```

For me at least this way works on android (same device).

PS. My "PreviousScene" object always contain the whole level (it wrap everything)

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. I already tried that, but can not find an error message, that indicates that there is a problem. I added a Screenshot of the Logcat Debug output, in the Original Question. Maybe you can find something that indicates an error there

Comment: @Felpower maybe just try LoadSceneAsync... I think the problem can be that android is too slow to load that scene in realtime... just a guess but worth trying... I will check how I load scene in my own project that work on android while you try

Comment: Thanks for that information. I already tried loading it async and waiting for it to be loaded and then setting it as the active scene, but it was still not working. Is there maybe any special way i have to add scenes to android? Or should it be enough to have them in the Build Settings?

Comment: I do it like this: Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("PreviousScene")); SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Name New Level", LoadSceneMode.Additive); Not sure if it will work for you too. Also since I stop time when the game is in the menu before that I will set Time.timeScale = 1.0f; For me at least this way works on android (same device). PS. My "PreviousScene" object always contain the whole level (it wrap everything)

Comment: Thank you, i will try that as soon as i get home

Comment: Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("PreviousScene"));
I do not have a GameObject, I have a Scene, why are you trying to Destroy a GameObject?

Comment: @Felpower I got my whole scene in a gameobject so that I can destroy it before I create a new scene since I use LoadSceneMode.Additive (or I will end up with multiple level in background).

Comment: Somehow i managed to make it work, by simply changing the m_ShowUnitySplashScreen from 0 to 1, i do not fully understand why it is working now, but it somehow does. Thanks anyway for your input. Appreciate it